# C# Ping - how many attempts?

Tags: c#, ip-address, ping

I am using the System.Net.NetworkInformation library to ping an IP address to test connectivity. I am wondering how many attempts it will try before failing? For example, if you ping in CMD, it tries 4 times. Also if it tries multiple attempts, how does it declare success or failure when some fail and some pass?

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From reading this line of the documentation, it sounds like it attempts only once.

`This method sends to the host that is specified by address a 32 Byte data buffer with the ICMP echo message. The method waits five seconds for an ICMP echo reply message. If it does not receive a reply in that time, the method returns and the Status property is set to TimedOut.`

Comment: Obviously didn't look at the documentation very hard.

Comment: It's all in the documentation you just have to read.

Comment: Well here goes the documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Ping.Send()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hzczzed(v=vs.110).aspx) method will send a single buffer and wait for timeout.

As per that reference:

> This method sends a **32 Byte data buffer** with the ICMP echo message. **The method waits five seconds for an ICMP echo reply message**. *If it does not receive a reply in that time, the method returns and the Status property is set to TimedOut.*

So to directly answer your question, it'll be **1 attempt**.

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `Ping.Send()` will send a single ICMP message and block until a response is received, an error occurs, or the timeout expires.